# How to show that entries of this matrix are in $L^\infty(0,T)$?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I have a problem.

Let $A(t)$ be a $n \times n$ matrix for each $t \in [0,b]$ with the property for all vectors $x$ that
$$x^TA(t)x \geq C|x|^2$$
where $C$ doesn't depend on $t$. Can I use this fact to tell me that $A(t)$ has entries all in $L^\infty(0,T)$?

All I know is that $A(t)^{-1}$ exists, and each of its entries are in $L^\infty(0,T)$. And $A(t)^{-1}$ is also positive-definite, BUT the constant is not necessarily independent of $t$.

Comment: Isn't $A(t) = (1 + t^{-1})\mathbb{I}$ a counterexample?

Comment: But $A(t)$ is not defined at $0$, right?

Comment: Oh, didn't realise it was $[0,T]$... without a continuity assumption you can still have an unbounded $A(t)$, though.

Comment: Anthony is of course right: there is no reason for the entries of $A(t)$ to be in $L^\infty$. Take $n=1$, and  let $A:[0,T]\to \mathbb R$ be any function which is not in $L^\infty$ but satisfies $A(t)\geq 1$ for all $t$. Then your assumption is satisfied with $C=1$.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments